# Unable to drag and drop into PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, picturebox

I am having issues Dragging and Dropping into a Picturebox in my Winforms Application.  I am getting an icon that looks like [this](http://www.clipartpal.com/_thumbs/00200027333_tns.png) when I try to drag and drop a picture.  It appears that it is not taking the AllowDrop I am applying to the picture box.  All methods are initialized in the designer.

This is the code in my form:

```
   private void Overlay_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pbx_OverlayImage.AllowDrop = true;
    }

    private void pbx_OverlayImage_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("YAY");
        pbx_OverlayImage.Image = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, true);
    }

    private void pbx_OverlayImage_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        // See if this is a copy and the data includes an image.
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap) &&
            (e.AllowedEffect & DragDropEffects.Copy) != 0)
        {
            // Allow this.
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }
        else
        {
            // Don't allow any other drop.
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
    }

    private void pbx_OverlayImage_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var img = pbx_OverlayImage.Image;
        if (img == null) return;
        if (DoDragDrop(img, DragDropEffects.Move) == DragDropEffects.Move)
        {
            pbx_OverlayImage.Image = null;
            return;
        }
        pbx_OverlayImage.DoDragDrop(pbx_OverlayImage.Image,
        DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
```

This is the code I use to call the Form:

```
        var form = new Overlay {lbl_Title = {Text = txbx_OverlayName.Text}, pbx_OverlayImage = {AllowDrop = true}};
        //var form = new test();
        form.Show();
```

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: What are you dragging onto the PB? An image or a file of an image?

Comment: Actually, the icon suggests that it is failing your test in `DragEnter`.

Comment: @DonBoitnott - That was exactly the problem (I will be appending this).  I was trying to move a png when it was looking for a bmp.  I adjusted the code to search the file extension and that made it work.